# Confusion about file I/O (C)

Tags: c, file-io

```
fwrite(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
while(!feof(p))
{
    printf("flag");
    fread(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",studentg.name,studentg.add,studentg.tel,studentg.pc,studentg.qq,studentg.email);
}
```

Why I put only one object in file,but it output two same line?
And if I put two objects in file,it output one object correct,but another repeated.
I try show feof(p)'s return value,it show me that after fread ,feof(p)'s return value is still 0.Can anyone explain how it happens?

Comment: You didn't read the comp.lang.c FAQ nor the feof man page. EOF is only detected *after* an operation, never before and you must seek when switching from write to read operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get an end of file until you try to read beyond the file. This means that you have to check eof before the print:

```
fwrite(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
finish = 0;
while(!finish)
{
    printf("flag");
    fread(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
    finish = feof(p);
    if (!finish)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",studentg.name,studentg.add,studentg.tel,studentg.pc,studentg.qq,studentg.email);
    }
}
```

or

```
fwrite(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
while(1)
{
    printf("flag");
    fread(&studentg,sizeof(studentg),1,p);
    if (feof(p)) break;
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",studentg.name,studentg.add,studentg.tel,studentg.pc,studentg.qq,studentg.email);
}
```

Comment: Oh, an additional comment... fwrite and then fread won't work. You need to seek to the start of file after write or, may better, to close the file and open it again for reading.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/:

"This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file."

This means that end of file is usually detected after an operation.

To fix your code, you may for example replace the condition in while loop with 1 or true and break execution when eof is reached (run feof inside loop).

Answer (score 2):

Use of feof is one of the biggest misconception among beginners in File I/O. Everybody at some point has done the same mistake once or twice.

The way you have used it is Pascal's way but C way is different. The difference is::

1. Pascal's function returns true if the next read will fail because of end of file.
2. C's function returns true if the last function failed.

Thats why your code prints the last line twice because after the last line is read in and printed out, feof() will still return 0 (false) and the loop will continue. The next fgets() fails and so the line variable holding the contents of the last line is not changed and is printed out again. After this, feof() will return true (since fgets() failed) and the loop ends.

The correct way to use it is::

```
while( 1 ) {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    if ( feof(fp) )    /* check for EOF right after fgets() */
      break;
    fputs(line, stdout);
  }
```

Still better way::

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL )
    fputs(line, stdout);
```

Comment: The C idiom for nonterminating loops is `for(;;)` (which also avoids lint warnings about constant expression in boolean context.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should include a complete, reproducing, example to what you want to do, not a combined fragment of the code, which is hard to reproduce. Otherwise, note that using fwrite()/fread() on struct contents directly [is not portable](https://github.com/shlomif/Freenode-programming-channel-FAQ/blob/master/FAQ.mdwn#how-should-i-do-binary-inputoutput-properly) (see the free online book [Porting UNIX Software](http://www.lemis.com/grog/Documentation/PUS/)), and is prone to errors. But you didn't provide enough context for us to understand what went wrong.